# How do i get oblivion to stop crashing?

Tags: 12.04, wine, playonlinux

I'm using Ubuntu Distribution 12.04 and trying to run Oblivion, I used playonlinux to install it to a virtual drive along with using wine.

I think the problem is I have a bugged graphics card or something I'm fairly new to Linux just moved from windows. Here is the bug report from playonlinux I believe.

When I start it up on playonlinux, it shows a menu with the buttons, "Play, Data Files, Options, Elderscrolls.com, Technical Support, Uninstall, and Exit".

```
[10/19/13 14:58:38] - Running wine-1.7.4 OblivionLauncher.exe (Working directory : /home/tyler/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/TheElderScrolls4_Oblivion/drive_c/Program Files/Bethesda Softworks/Oblivion)
wine: configuration in '/home/tyler/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/TheElderScrolls4_Oblivion' has been updated.
[10/19/13 14:59:02] - Running wine-1.7.4 regedit (Working directory : /home/tyler/.PlayOnLinux)
[10/19/13 14:59:02] - User modified something in the registry manually
[10/19/13 15:02:24] - Running wine-1.7.4 OblivionLauncher.exe (Working directory : /home/tyler/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/TheElderScrolls4_Oblivion/drive_c/Program Files/Bethesda Softworks/Oblivion)
[10/19/13 15:18:56] - Running wine-1.7.4 OblivionLauncher.exe (Working directory : /home/tyler/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/TheElderScrolls4_Oblivion/drive_c/Program Files/Bethesda Softworks/Oblivion)
[10/19/13 15:19:15] - Running wine-1.7.4 OblivionLauncher.exe (Working directory : /home/tyler/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/TheElderScrolls4_Oblivion/drive_c/Program Files/Bethesda Softworks/Oblivion)
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded
fixme:d3d:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)").
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f328,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)").
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33ef28,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)").
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33eef8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:state_zenable Z buffer disabled, but ARB_depth_clamp isn't supported.
```

Comment: Anyone know how to run oblivion? I have searched and searched, with no return.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer it has been 4 months if anyone is willing to help i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If you're running 64-bit Ubuntu it searches the 64 libraries first, then fails and closes. This will instruct it to search the 32 library first. This is how I solved the issue with Civilization 4.